# Execute JavaScript from String

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I want to run this script when button `A` is clicked. The script is stored in an Object as a string. When button A is clicked, I use eval, like: eval(Object[script]). This works fine, unless I have functions within the script, when I do, it breaks because they are not getting defined. Is there a way to get around this? I tried putting the function definition in a var and putting it at the top of the script. Now, if I simply copy my script to the console, it executes perfectly. Is there a way to execute a script as if it were typed into the console?

FYI: This is a simplification of my problem, I realize there are better ways to do what I describe here.

Comment: What error is showing in your console?

Comment: @pvnarula Function undefined of course. His question is very clear.

Comment: Try to use the eval("'"+ Object[script] +"'");

Comment: could you show a small sample that is not working, because this `eval("function test() {console.log('2')}; console.log('1'); test();"); test();` is working for me.

Comment: Can you post your object with function ?

Comment: Can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/watson/tSakL/

Comment: @watson `hi` is not defined. does this work for you http://jsfiddle.net/tSakL/1/ ?

Comment: You guys are right, i think, i must be messing something up

Comment: You tried to use `hi`, while you probably meant to say literal `'hi'`

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I mean other than that obvious mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
var oFunc = function (value) {
                    alert(value)
            }

var obj = { code: "oFunc('hello')" }

eval(obj["code"]);
```

Or am I missing something?

**Update**

This also works

```
var obj = { code: "var oFunc = function (value) {alert(value)}; oFunc('hello')" }
eval(obj["code"]);
```

Comment: yeah, to match my problem, oFunc should be defined inside obj['code'].

Answer (score 2):

The best fix is to **stop storing code as strings.**  Use functions instead.

```
buttonA.script = function() {
    do whatever you were doing in your eval
};

// then, instead of `eval(buttonA['script'])`, say...
buttonA.script();

// or, if the name is in a variable...
var foo = 'script'; // for example
buttonA[foo]();
```

About the only time `eval` makes sense is when you have code that by its very nature has to be dynamically generated or interpreted.  For the vast majority of cases, that is not true.  I can only think of a case where it would be true, in fact: the textarea script testing thing mentioned in the comments.

For every other case...

```
obj = {
    first: function() {
        function test() { alert('hi'); }
        test();
    }
};

obj['first']();
// or simply
obj.first();

// and what's more...`test` doesn't escape and trample on stuff.
try { test(); }
catch (ex) { alert("" + ex); }  says `test` is not defined
```

Comment: I guess the point is to use a `textarea` to allow the user to type the script and run it to see the results.

Comment: @BrunoLM: That would be just about the only case where `eval` makes sense.  Problem is, there's not a textarea in sight.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `alert(hi)` should be `alert("hi")`

```
obj = {
    first: 'function test() { alert("hi") } test();'
}
eval(obj["first"]);
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/tSakL/2/)